# Problem setting GPU as primary video card

Tags: nvidia, laptop, gpu

I'm new to linux and am having a bit of trouble setting my GPU up as my primary video adapter. That being said, a little background info is in order. I'm currently running linux on a MSI laptop that has an dedicated nVidia GeForce 1050 video card and a Intel chip that uses HD graphics. I want to set up the nVidia card as my primary so I can still play a few graphic intensive games every so often, games that the integrated graphics chokes on. I've searched the web for answers for a couple of days now and haven't found a solution that works for me yet.

**sudo lshw -C video** returns:

```
*-display                 
       description: 3D controller
       product: GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:140 memory:de000000-deffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:df000000-df07ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: HD Graphics 630
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 04
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:138 memory:dd000000-ddffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

[System Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5M9Lp.png)
[nVidia Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKHi6.png)
[Additional Drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLbn8.png)

Things I've Tried:

1. Using nVidia Prime and prime-select
2. Using nVidia Optimus
3. Installing Bumblebee and Bumblebee-nVidia
4. Purging and reinstalling drivers
5. Trying the Nouveau drivers (which actually caused linux to fail to display the UI and I had to purge the driver then reinstall the nVidia driver from tty)

I may have forgotten a couple of things but I'm willing to try anything and everything.

Comment: You've tried too many things (and a lot are really outdated). Currently all it needs is installing the proper Nvidia driver (using the Additional Drivers is recommend). Then, at Nvidia X Server Settings select the high performance profile and REBOOT. That's all.

Comment: I've tried applying the High Performance profile and rebooting but the System Settings still stays Im using the integrated Intel HD graphics. Does the system settings need to change to show which GPU I'm using?

Comment: It should change indeed. That said, considering you've been all over the place with your experiments, all bets are off.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Seems you are using proprietary drivers as of right now (as I can see in your screenshots.) **You can skip to step number 8**.

Please uninstall everything related to Nvidia in advance (nouveau should be installed and should be active if you are not using proprietary drivers by default). Especially `Bumblebee` it's very outdated and not recommended.

1. Then reboot your computer, launch `Software & Updates`
2. Select `Additional Drivers` tab as suggested in comments.
3. Select latest proprietary driver. `Using NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-470 (proprietary, tested)`
4. Click `Apply Changes` wait until it's finished. Type `sudo update-initramfs -u` to your terminal to rebuild your kernel modules. (Not necessary but just in case.)
5. Reboot your computer.
6. After that you have several options, you can use PRIME render offload or switching between Intel or Nvidia.
7. You can check out [Ubuntu Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia#NVIDIA_Optimus) for detailed information about Switchable Graphics. As far as I can see, you want to use just Nvidia card.
8. Launch `NVIDIA X Server Settings`, under the `PRIME Profiles` tab select `NVIDIA (High Performance)` setting or alternatively type `sudo prime-select nvidia` to your terminal. Restart your session (logout and login) or reboot your computer.

[image: X Server Settings]

9. Verify you are selected Nvidia with `sudo prime-select query`.
10. Type `glxinfo | grep vendor` to your terminal to determine which GPU you are using right now.